# js как через new Data можно росчитать сколько осталось до ДН или определеннгого дня?

Tags: javascript

Вот есть дата сегодня, и определенная дата.И как мне сосчитать сколько осталось месяцев и дней до того же времени что записано в переменной date?

```
let date = new Date(1999, 5, 21);
let nowDate = new Date();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let date = new Date(1999, 5, 21);
let nowDate = new Date();
let diff = new Date(nowDate - date);
```

Comment: Эх, если бы это было все так просто! Дело в том, что нельзя тут сразу сделать так, чтобы отображалось время до какого-либо события в годах. Это целый функционал, даже мини библиотечка на самом-то деле. с минимум 3-мя функциями наверное.

Comment: @СерегаМангышев да так б сделал сам, если можно было) , у меня плохо все с математикой, я так понял, надо брать месяц, день, и как то считать миллисекундах или как? Что то тяжело, или мне так кажется?

Answer (score 3):

Библиотека [`moment js`](https://momentjs.com/) в помощь.

```js
const from_date = moment([1999, 5, 21]);

const variants = ['years', 'months', 'days', 'hours', 'seconds'];

for (const variant of variants)
    console.log(
        variant.padEnd(7),
        ':',
        moment().diff(from_date, variant)
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let date = new Date(1999, 0, 12);
let nowDate = new Date();

let targetYear, targetMonth, targetDay, month, day, lastDayOfMonth, monthPast

month=nowDate.getMonth()
day=nowDate.getDate()

//Сколько месяцев до конца года
monthPast=11-date.getMonth()
//Количество месяцев с начала текущего года + количество месяцев оставшихся до конца года в заданной дате
//Отнимаем 1 месяц от заданной даты, так как месяц не полный и 1 месяц от текущей даты по той же причине
targetMonth=monthPast+month-2
//Сколько лет между датами. Отнимаем 1 год от заданной даты, так как год не полный и 1 год от текущей даты по той же причине
targetYear=nowDate.getFullYear()-date.getFullYear()-2
//Последний день месяца из заданной даты (нужен для подсчета оставшихся дней в месяце)
lastDayOfMonth=new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1,01-1).getDate()
//Количество дней, оставшихся до конца месяца в заданной дате + количество прошедших дней в текущем месяце
targetDay=lastDayOfMonth-date.getDate()+day
//Проверка на переполнение
if(targetMonth>11){
  targetYear++
  targetMonth=targetMonth-11
}
targetMonth=targetMonth+1
console.log('до даты осталось лет: '+targetYear+', месяцев: '+targetMonth+', дней: '+targetDay)
```

Выглядит наверное кривовато, но стандартных инструментов а-ля "решение за одну функцию" не увидел